Why I can not look for entities between joined tables?
I have two entities User and Phone.
User Entity:
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_table")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    @NonNull
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastname")
    @NonNull
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "age")
    @NonNull
    private Integer age;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NonNull
    private String email;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_address_id"))
    private Address address;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "phone_number", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user_phone_number"))
    private Phone phone;
}

Phone Entity :
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone_table")
public class Phone {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "phone_number", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    private String number;
}

Also I created a DTO classes of these Entities.
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class CreateUserRequest {
    private Long userId;
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer age;
    private String email;
    private CreatePhoneRequest phone;
    private CreateAddressRequest address;
}

@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class UserResponse {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private int age;
    private PhoneResponse phone;
    private AddressResponse address;
    }
}

and
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class CreatePhoneRequest {
    private String phone;
}
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class PhoneResponse {
    private String phone;
}

Then UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Long, User> where I findUserByPhone_Number(String phonenumber)
in service I make the logic for looking for users:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PhoneServiceImpl phoneServiceImpl;

    //    ***********************************************************
    //    ******************* FIND USER BY PHONE ********************
    //    ***********************************************************
    @NonNull
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public UserResponse getUserByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        return userRepository.findUserByPhone_Number(phoneNumber);
    } 
}

and UserController for  making requests:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {
    private final UserServiceImpl userService;
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);

    @GetMapping(value = "/phonenumber/{number}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public UserResponse getUserByPhoneNumber(@PathVariable String number) {
        UserResponse user = userService.getUserByPhoneNumber(number);
        System.out.println(user);
        return user;
    }
}

And I can get list of users, I can get user by ID..... but when I try to get user by phoneNumber (Joined Table), I receive :
{
    "message": "Specified result type [com.app.apringlearn.app.ResponseRequest.UserResponse] did not match Query selection type [com.app.apringlearn.app.Enteties.User] - multiple selections: use Tuple or array"
}


Can you restict your post to one question? It is already long enough. Also you can strip unnecesary details like full list of fields that irrelevant. Also add full stack of your error.

i guess now is better....

Your repository is returning a UserResponse instead of a User. Not sure why. It should return a User not a UserResponse. This is also what the exception is telling you.

These are classes of objects that will be received and sent by our controllers. That would not give the domain models and not to open the information about the database, besides, it is easier to extend their models and pass any amount of information through them. These are good practices.

Add code of UserRepository

just make your getUserByPhoneNumber return User but not UserResponse
@NonNull
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public User getUserByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        return userRepository.findUserByPhone_Number(phoneNumber);
    } 

and change all the linking classes accordingly.
it should work as you expect...
